# Difference between Text and IText in fabricJS

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

Can someone please tell me what makes `fabric.IText` different from `fabric.Text`? Any demo I can look at? Official Fabric tutorial only [describes Text](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-2/#text) and I see no difference with usage in [official IText demo](http://fabricjs.com/test/misc/itext.html).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In Text: You can set any style (like fill,textBackgroundColor,fontSize...etc) , it will be applied to "whole text".

But in IText: You can set styles to "any number of characters(you selected)" from your text and it will be applied to the selected part of text only.

For selecting characters from Itext you can use :

- Create selection: click/touch & drag, Select word: double click and Select line: triple click

  or, [follow IText docs](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.IText.html)

  and try again [IText Examples](http://fabricjs.com/test/misc/itext.html)

Comment: that answers the question, thanx

Comment: i cannt vote up since i dont have enough reputation, but thanx

Comment: sorry i didnt see the grey-green check mark, thanx again :D